# AndroidPieChart will not show

Tags: android, charts, statistics, draw, pie-chart

This is my XML :

```
    <net.kenyang.piechart.PieChart
    android:id="@+id/pieChart"
    android:layout_below="@id/id_bar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

This is the code that I use for the piechart to be initialised:

```
 ArrayList<PieChartData> alPercentage = new ArrayList<PieChartData>();
    alPercentage.add(new PieChartData(55.0f, "1"));
    alPercentage.add(new PieChartData(45.0f, "2"));
    try {
        // setting data
        pieChart.setAdapter(alPercentage);

        // setting a listener
        pieChart.setOnSelectedListener(new PieChart.OnSelectedLisenter() {
            @Override
            public void onSelected(int iSelectedIndex) {
                Toast.makeText(PSTravelStatisticsActivity.this, "Select index:" + iSelectedIndex, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
        pieChart.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        pieChart.invalidate();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.i("","error is : " + e.getMessage());
        if (e.getMessage().equals(PieChart.ERROR_NOT_EQUAL_TO_100)){
            Log.e("kenyang", "percentage is not equal to 100");
        }
    }
```

Now it doesn't give me an error
If I try making it in such a way that the percentage is less than 100, but then it throws an exception. So that means that with this logic, it should work, it does send me 2 logs, but thats it:

```
10-08 16:10:11.556  12591-12591/nl.hgrams.passenger I/net.kenyang.piechart.PieChart﹕ PieChart init
10-08 16:10:11.626  12591-12591/nl.hgrams.passenger I/net.kenyang.piechart.PieChart﹕ onDraw
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did it like this and it worked then:

```
 final PieRenderer pieRenderer = pieChart.getRenderer(PieRenderer.class);
        pieRenderer.setDonutSize((float) 75 / 100, PieRenderer.DonutMode.PERCENT);
        selectDataType();
        pieChart.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                if(pieRenderer.getContainingSegment(new PointF(event.getX(), event.getY())) == bikeS){
                    segment = 0;
                    selectSegment(segment, true);
                }
                if(pieRenderer.getContainingSegment(new PointF(event.getX(), event.getY())) == carS){
                    segment = 1;
                    selectSegment(segment, true);
                }
                if(pieRenderer.getContainingSegment(new PointF(event.getX(), event.getY())) == transitS){
                    segment = 2;
                    selectSegment(segment, true);
                }
                if(pieRenderer.getContainingSegment(new PointF(event.getX(), event.getY())) == walkS){
                    segment = 3;
                    selectSegment(segment, true);
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
   pieChart.removeSegment(carS);
    pieChart.removeSegment(walkS);
    pieChart.removeSegment(transitS);
    pieChart.removeSegment(bikeS);
  bikeS = new Segment("", tm.getBicycling());
                carS = new Segment("", tm.getDriving());
                transitS = new Segment("", tm.getTransit());
                walkS = new Segment("", tm.getWalking());
                pieChart.addSeries(bikeS, new SegmentFormatter(bikeCP, bikeCP, bikeCP, bikeCP));
                pieChart.addSeries(carS, new SegmentFormatter(carC, carC, carC, carC));
                pieChart.addSeries(transitS, new SegmentFormatter(transitC, transitC, transitC, transitC));
                pieChart.addSeries(walkS, new SegmentFormatter(walkC, walkC, walkC, walkC));
                typeText.setText(getString(R.string.bike));
                typePercent.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.bike_color));
                typeImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.profile_travel_mode_pie_bicycling);
  pieChart.invalidate();
```

Comment: doesnt work for me like this - any chance of sharing the solution on the issue for the github project?

Comment: Sorry, but I changed my workspace since then and I no longer have access to that code :(